# Keras - what accuracy metric should be used along with sparse_categorical_crossentropy to compile model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cross-entropy

When I have 2 classes I used `binary_crossentropy` as `loss` value like this to compile a model:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But right now I have 5 classes & I'm not using on hot encoded features. So I choose `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as `loss` value. But what should be the accuracy metric as [keras metric](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py) source code suggested there are multiple accuracy metrics available. I tried:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

So is it correct or should I just use `categorical_accuracy`?

Answer (score 2):

> `sparse_categorical_accuracy` is a correct metrics for
>   `sparse_categorical_entropy`.

But why are you using `sparse_categorical_entropy`? What kind of classes do you have? `sparse_categorical_entropy` is being used for **Integer** outputs. But if you have a **one-hot-encoded** target, you should use `categorical_crossentropy` as *loss function* and `accuracy` or `categorical_accuracy` for *metrics*.

---

**UPDATE:**
Use the following code for your classification problem:

```
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I don't know how to use one-hot-encoded. Thats why I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594864/how-to-use-one-hot-encoded-ouput-vector-with-dense-to-train-a-model-in-keras)

Comment: Use `keras.utils.to_categorical` function.

Comment: I already generated one-hot-encoded vector but I don't know how to use it creating the model. Can you show me any example for that?